# Pyspark Extract Values from from Array of maps in structured streaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, nested, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following schema:

```
root
 |-- sents: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- metadata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: map (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

In a table it looks like this:

```
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|sents     |metadata                                                             |
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[1, -1, 0]|[[confidence -> 0.4991], [confidence -> 0.5378], [confidence -> 0.0]]|
+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I access the te Value from this list of maps within the array column?

thank you

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: So far I'e tried to create  a df that contains each value in a separate column, the problem is that the solution is not dynamic because I cannot do a .collect() or .take() in structured streaming. I'm trying to do aggregate functions between the array column -sents-  and a and array of maps column -metadata- but I'm not sure how to proceed. AVG[sents_i * metadata_i] for i in range(len(metadata))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options using [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#explode) and [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) high-order function in Spark.

**Option 1 (explode + pyspark accessors)**

First we `explode` elements of the array into a new column, next we access the map using the key `metadata` to retrieve the value:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, expr

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [[{"confidence":0.4991}, {"confidence":0.5378}, {"confidence":0.0}]]
], ["metadata"])

df.select(explode(col("metadata")).alias("metadata")) \
  .select(col("metadata")["confidence"].alias("value"))

# +------+
# |value |
# +------+
# |0.4991|
# |0.5378|
# |0.0   |
# +------+
```

**Option 2 (transform + explode)**

Here we use `transform` to extract the values of the map into a new array and then we `explode` it:

```py
df.select(explode(expr("transform(metadata, i -> i['confidence'])")).alias("value"))
```